# Make Table thead fix and tbody scroll using CSS

Tags: html, css

Good Morning, I am facing a new problem. I want to fixed table header which have colspan and rowspan. when i scroll the table, the full header can not fixed. only 2 rows fix an another one row can not fixed. Table header like the below
[image]

But when i scroll the table . the header looks like the below
[image]

I used only css. Here is my css and html:

```css
.fixHeader {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.fixHeader th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #b4bab4;
}

.fixHeader table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.fixHeader th,
.fixHeader td {
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
}

.table-scroll table {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.table-scroll th,
.table-scroll td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-scroll thead th {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

th.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #ccc;
}

thead th.sticky {
  z-index: 5;
}

.table-scroll thead tr:nth-child(2) th {
  top: 30px;
}

And my table is like
```

```html
<div class="table-scroll">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="107" rowspan="3">fgf</th>
        <th width="107" rowspan="3">gdfg</th>
        <th colspan="6">fg</th>
        <th width="92" rowspan="2">gfdg</th>
        <th width="48" rowspan="2">dfgd</th>
        <th width="33" rowspan="3">xzxX</th>
        <th width="118" rowspan="3">dfgsdfg</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">dg</th>
        <th colspan="3">dfg</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th width="107">fg</th>
        <th width="107">sdfg</th>
        <th width="107">dfg</th>
        <th width="107">dfg</th>
        <th width="107">dfg</th>
        <th width="58">dfg</th>
        <th>sdfg</th>
        <th>dfg</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>test_data</td>
        <td>test_data</td>
        <td>test_data</td>
        <td>test_data</td>
        <td>test_data</td>
        <td>test_data</td>
        <td>test_data</td>
        <td>test_data</td>
        <td>test_data</td>
        <td>test_data</td>
        <td>test_data</td>
        <td>test_data</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Please help me.

Comment: it is better to use grid instead of table

Comment: It was better but not possible at this moment. Because  where it will use, there were used bootstrap table.

Comment: `fixHeader` is not included in your HTML.

Comment: Same thing goes while i add fixHeader